# How to deliver a baseline from one project to another project in UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am having 2 projects in clearcase UCM as follows

```
Project-200
Project-200.1
```

In Project-200.1 , We have completed a work and applied a baseline

> "Project-200.1-1.1.0.0"

Now we would like to deliver from Project-200.1 to Project-200.

How to deliver the baselined contents? We do not want to deliver any thing which is added after baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply make an inter-project deliver of your baseline.
As long as both projects have the same component, and if the **deliver policy of the destination project** authorize inter-delivers, you can initiate it between a stream of `Project-200.1` and a Stream of `Project-200`.

[image: deliver policies]

For specifying a target Stream which is different from the default one (ie different from its immediate parent Stream), you need to [initiate a "deliver to alternate target"](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/t_start_deliver_nondef_target.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the picture is bogus. I think "Allow interproject deliver to project or stream" has to be enabled.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu yes,  the picture was just an illustration from IBM website, not tailored specifically for this question. You can see the policy I mention though.